# Grouping the rows by similarities

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I am working on SQL server.

I have the following table:

For each BIGroup I have a multiple VarianceName.
For each VarianceName I have multiple PartNumbers.
I am comparing every partnumber with the other partnumbers within the same BIGroup and VarianceName, and writting the number of differences between PartNumber1 and PartNumber2 in the column Difference:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| BIGroup | VarianceName | PartNumber1 | PartNumber2 | Difference |  Cluster  |
+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    11426777 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    11426781 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    12542804 |          2 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    12554759 |          4 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    12564258 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    11426777 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    11426781 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    12542804 |          5 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    12554759 |          1 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    12564258 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    11426777 |          2 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    11426781 |          5 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    12542804 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    12554759 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    12564258 |          8 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    11426777 |          4 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    11426781 |          1 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    12542804 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    12554759 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    12564258 |          9 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    11426777 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    11426781 |          0 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    12542804 |          8 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    12554759 |          9 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    12564258 |          0 |           |
| D934    | AA           |    11438878 |    11438878 |          0 |           |
| D934    | AB           |    11438924 |    11438924 |          0 |           |
| D934    | AC           |    12556213 |    12556213 |          0 |           |
| D934    | AC           |    12556213 |    12556214 |          5 |           |
| D934    | AC           |    12556214 |    12556213 |          5 |           |
| D934    | AC           |    12556214 |    12556214 |          0 |           |
| D955    | A            |    75346846 |    75346846 |          0 |           |
| ...     | ...          |    ...      |    ...      |          0 |           |
+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

ex: 
For D934, for VarianceName A, PartNumbers 11426777, 11426781 and 12564258 are identical because there is 0 differences between :
11426777 and 11426781,
11426781 and 12564258, and
12564258 and 11426777.

ex: 
For D934, for VarianceName A, PartNumbers 12542804 and 12554759 are identical because there is 0
differences between:
12542804  and 12554759.

**My Goal is to identify all the group of identical PartNumbers within the same BIGroup and VarianceName.**
To flag those groups, I will use the column called **Cluster**.

So 11426777, 11426781 and 12564258 would belong to Cluster D934-A-C1.

So 12542804 and 12554759 would belong to cluster D934-A-C2.

**What should be the query/stored procedure to update the Cluster column**, to obtain the following result:

```
+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| BIGroup | VarianceName | PartNumber1 | PartNumber2 | Difference |  Cluster  |
+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    11426777 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    11426781 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    12542804 |          2 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    12554759 |          4 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426777 |    12564258 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    11426777 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    11426781 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    12542804 |          5 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    12554759 |          1 |           |
| D934    | A            |    11426781 |    12564258 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    11426777 |          2 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    11426781 |          5 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    12542804 |          0 | D934-A-C2 |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    12554759 |          0 | D934-A-C2 |
| D934    | A            |    12542804 |    12564258 |          8 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    11426777 |          4 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    11426781 |          1 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    12542804 |          0 | D934-A-C2 |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    12554759 |          0 | D934-A-C2 |
| D934    | A            |    12554759 |    12564258 |          9 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    11426777 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    11426781 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    12542804 |          8 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    12554759 |          9 |           |
| D934    | A            |    12564258 |    12564258 |          0 | D934-A-C1 |
```

And so on for the other VarianceName

```
| D934    | AA           |    11438878 |    11438878 |          0 | D934-AA-C1  
| D934    | AB           |    11438924 |    11438924 |          0 | D934-AB-C1
| D934    | AC           |    12556213 |    12556213 |          0 | D934-AC-C1
| D934    | AC           |    12556213 |    12556214 |          5 |
| D934    | AC           |    12556214 |    12556213 |          5 |
| D934    | AC           |    12556214 |    12556214 |          0 | D934-AC-C1
```

And so on for the other BiGroup

```
| D955    | A            |    75346846 |    75346846 |          0 | D955-A-C1
| ...     | ...          |    ...      |    ...      |        ... |
+---------+--------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

The column should be left to NULL if Difference > 0

Here is the script to have the data as a cte:

```
with t1 as
( 
select 'D934'  as BIGroup  ,'A'    as VarianceName  ,   11426777 as PartNumber1,   11426777 as PartNumber2,         0 as Difference,  null as Cluster        
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426777 ,   11426781 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426777 ,   12542804 ,         2 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426777 ,   12554759 ,         4 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426777 ,   12564258 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426781 ,   11426777 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426781 ,   11426781 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426781 ,   12542804 ,         5 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426781 ,   12554759 ,         1 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   11426781 ,   12564258 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12542804 ,   11426777 ,         2 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12542804 ,   11426781 ,         5 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12542804 ,   12542804 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12542804 ,   12554759 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12542804 ,   12564258 ,         8 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12554759 ,   11426777 ,         4 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12554759 ,   11426781 ,         1 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12554759 ,   12542804 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12554759 ,   12554759 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12554759 ,   12564258 ,         9 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12564258 ,   11426777 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12564258 ,   11426781 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12564258 ,   12542804 ,         8 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12564258 ,   12554759 ,         9 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'A'            ,   12564258 ,   12564258 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'AA'           ,   11438878 ,   11438878 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'AB'           ,   11438924 ,   11438924 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'AC'           ,   12556213 ,   12556213 ,         0 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'AC'           ,   12556213 ,   12556214 ,         5 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'AC'           ,   12556214 ,   12556213 ,         5 , null
union select 'D934'    ,'AC'           ,   12556214 ,   12556214 ,         0 , null
union select 'D955'    ,'A'            ,   75346846 ,   75346846 ,         0 , null
)
```

**Edit:**
To better understand the problem, I drew the 5 partnumbers of `D934` `A`, their links, and the two clusters.

The links we are interested in are the black ones (because it means there is 0 differences between the partNumbers).

The orange links are representing difference>0 between the partNumbers.

After drawing the links we can identify 2 clusters, which I drew with red circles.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @BiGroup                    [nvarchar](30);
DECLARE @VarianceName               [nvarchar](30);
DECLARE @NewBiGroup                 [nvarchar](30);
DECLARE @NewVarianceName            [nvarchar](30);
DECLARE @PartNumber                 [nvarchar](30);
DECLARE @ClusterName                [nvarchar](30);
DECLARE @IncrementClusterName       [nvarchar](30);

set @BiGroup = 'first_BiGroup';
set @VarianceName = 'first_VarianceName';
set @IncrementClusterName = 1;
set @ClusterName = null;

-- Declare cursor
DECLARE cur CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
Select [PartNumber1] FROM t1
order by [BIGroup] ,[VarianceName] ,[PartNumber1];

--clean cluster column
update t1 set [Cluster]=null;

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @PartNumber

-- Loop on every PartNumber
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  --set NewBiGroup and NewPartNumber
  set @NewBiGroup = (select Top(1) [BIGroup] from t1 where partnumber1 = @PartNumber);
  set @NewVarianceName = (select Top(1) [VarianceName] from t1 where partnumber1 = @PartNumber);

  --check if we are still in the same BIGroup and Variance, otherwise, reset the cluster increment
  if @NewBiGroup <> @BiGroup or @NewVarianceName <> @VarianceName 
  BEGIN
    set @IncrementClusterName = 1;
  END

  --get the clusterName of this partNumber, if it exists
  set @ClusterName = (select Top(1) [Cluster] from t1 where partnumber2 = @PartNumber and [Cluster] is not null);

  --if ClusterName is NULL, put a clustername and then increment the @IncrementClusterName, 
  --otherwise set the cluster to @ClusterName
  if @ClusterName is null
  BEGIN
    update t1 set [Cluster] = @NewBiGroup+'-'+@NewVarianceName+'-'+@IncrementClusterName
    where partnumber1 = @PartNumber  
    and Difference= 0 ;

    set @IncrementClusterName = @IncrementClusterName +1;
  END
  else
  BEGIN
    update t1 set [Cluster] = @NewBiGroup+'-'+@NewVarianceName+'-'+@ClusterName
    where partnumber1 = @PartNumber  
    and Difference= 0 ;
  END

  -- setting the BiGroup and VarianceName
  set @BiGroup = @NewBiGroup;
  set @VarianceName = @NewVarianceName;

 FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @PartNumber
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

The algorithm of the stored procedure works like this:

- For every `PartNumber` with Difference=0

  - If the `BiGroup` or `VarianceName` has changed

    - I reset the `@clusterIncrement` to 1
  - If he isn't already part of a `Cluster`

    - I set his `Cluster` to `@clusterIncrement`
    - `@clusterIncrement = @clusterIncrement +1`
  - If he is already part of a `Cluster`

    - I set his `Cluster` to the existing `Cluster`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DENSE_RANK to generate a number per Cluster.

When that rank is then concatinated to BIGroup & VarianceName, you'll get a cluster code.

The difficulty then is to find something common between those clusters.

The query below uses a trick where it calculates the minimum & sum of the PartNumber2 for the 0 differences.
And the uses those for the DENSE_RANK.

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT *
  , P2Min0 = MIN(CASE WHEN Difference = 0 THEN PartNumber2 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY BIGroup, VarianceName, PartNumber1)
  , P2Sum0 = SUM(CASE WHEN Difference = 0 THEN PartNumber2 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY BIGroup, VarianceName, PartNumber1)
  FROM t1
)
, CTE2 AS
(
SELECT *
  , Rnk = DENSE_RANK()
          OVER (PARTITION BY BIGroup, VarianceName ORDER BY P2Min0, P2Sum0)
  FROM CTE1
  WHERE Difference = 0
)
UPDATE CTE2
SET Cluster = CONCAT(BIGroup, '-', VarianceName, '-', Rnk)
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e0339e52073ec7f083c1af20d11901f)*

Comment: This could help me to generate the Cluster Name, but it does not help me to identify the group of similar `PartNumber`

Comment: @JohanB When I noticed that image you added, only then I understood what was ment by Clusters.  So I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH cte_p(BIGroup, VarianceName, PartNumber1, PartNumber2)
AS
(
    SELECT BIGroup, VarianceName, PartNumber1, PartNumber2
    FROM t1 
    WHERE [Difference]=0
),
cte_c(BIGroup, VarianceName, PartNumber1, PartNumber2, COrder)
AS
(
    SELECT p1.BIGroup, p1.VarianceName, p1.PartNumber1, p1.PartNumber2,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p1.BIGroup, p1.VarianceName ORDER BY p1.PartNumber1) AS COrder
    FROM cte_p p1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte_p p2
        WHERE p2.PartNumber1<>p2.PartNumber2
        AND p1.BIGroup=p2.BIGroup
        AND p1.VarianceName=p2.VarianceName
        AND p1.PartNumber1=p2.PartNumber2)
)

SELECT t.*,t.BIGroup+'-'+t.VarianceName+'-C'+CAST(c.COrder AS nvarchar(20))
FROM t1 t
INNER JOIN cte_c c
ON t.BIGroup=c.BIGroup
AND t.VarianceName=c.VarianceName
AND t.PartNumber1=c.PartNumber1;
```

Comment: Just added the c alias to your answer P

Comment: Thank you it was missing,  but this query is not solving the problem.
It is important to understand that in the example, 11426777 and 12542804 don't belong to the same cluster.

Comment: You need to post the script to create the table and populate the sample data in order for us to test it.

Comment: Hi PeterH, I have added to the Q a script to create the data as a cte